# SQL query error in PySpark while using temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server, apache-spark-sql

I have a SQL query which I have to access in PySpark(DataBricks). due to complex query, PySpark is not able to read the same. can someone check my query and assist me to get this query written in a single 'SELECT' statement  not using 'WITH' statement.

```
promotions = """
(WITH VCTE_Promotions as 
(SELECT v.Shortname, 
v.Employee_ID_ALT, v.Job_Level, 
v.Management_Level, 
CAST(sysdatetime() AS date) AS PIT_Date, 
v.Employee_Status_Alt as Employee_Status, 
v.Work_Location_Region, v.Work_Location_Country_Desc, v.HML, 
dbo.T_Mngmt_Level_IsManager_Mapping.IsManager
FROM Worker_CUR as v LEFT OUTER JOIN
dbo.T_Mngmt_Level_IsManager_Mapping ON v.Management_Level = dbo.T_Mngmt_Level_IsManager_Mapping.Management_Level),
VCTE_Promotion_v2_Eval as (
SELECT        Employee_ID_ALT,
                             (SELECT MAX(PIT_Date) AS prior_data
                               FROM  dbo.V_Worker_PIT_with_IsManager AS t
                               WHERE (employee_id_alt = a.Employee_ID_ALT) AND (PIT_Date < a.PIT_Date) AND (IsManager <> a.IsManager) OR
                               (employee_id_alt = a.Employee_ID_ALT) AND (PIT_Date < a.PIT_Date) AND (Job_Level <> a.Job_Level)) AS prev_job_change_date, IsManager
FROM            VCTE_Promotions AS a)

SELECT  VCTE_Promotion_v2_Eval.Employee_ID_ALT,
                         COALESCE (v_cur.Employee_Type, N'') AS Curr_Employee_Type,                          
                         v_cur.Review_Rating_Current
FROM VCTE_Promotion_v2_Eval INNER JOIN
[DM_GlobalStaff].[dbo].[V_Worker_CUR] as v_cur ON VCTE_Promotion_v2_Eval.Employee_ID_ALT = v_cur.Employee_ID_ALT LEFT OUTER JOIN
dbo.V_Worker_PIT_with_IsManager as v_m ON VCTE_Promotion_v2_Eval.prev_job_change_date = v_m.PIT_Date AND 
VCTE_Promotion_v2_Eval.Employee_ID_ALT = v_m.employee_id_alt ) as promotions
"""

promotions = spark.read.jdbc(url=jdbcUrl, table=promotions, properties=connectionProperties)
```

your Prompt assistance will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What is the error? @Sanjiv

Comment: This is not working in PySpark.
    Error:
    com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near 
    the keyword &apos;SELECT&apos;. 

    Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o200.jdbc. : 
    com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near 
   the keyword 'SELECT'. at 
  
 com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseErro 
 (SQLServerException.java:258) at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1535)